# Cannot connect to SSH server: port 22: No route to host

Tags: ssh

I want to connect my laptop to a router running ssh server with the static IP address of `192.168.0.1` on the ethernet interface. I could do so previously, but now for some reason, it says `ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.1 port 22: No route to host`. Previously that I could connect to the server, my laptop's way of acquiring IP address was `Automatic (DHCP)`, but now it does not connect on `Automatic`. I set the laptop's IP to static `192.168.0.66`. Here is the output for `route` command: (the ethernet interface is `enp3s0f1`)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         rtr-35-12-211-1 0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s0
roswell.egr.msu rtr-35-12-211-1 255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlp4s0
35.12.211.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp3s0f1
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp3s0f1
```

Here is the output from `ifconfig`:

```
enp3s0f1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr X:X:X:X:cb:2b  
          inet addr:192.168.0.66  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1c11:5c64:f2dd:91b6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:984 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:142942 (142.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3960 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3960 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:379355 (379.3 KB)  TX bytes:379355 (379.3 KB)

wlp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr X:X:X:X:7a:0d  
          inet addr:35.12.211.223  Bcast:35.12.211.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::280b:9f10:ce0d:7d94/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:300950 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:58621 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:321081707 (321.0 MB)  TX bytes:10520862 (10.5 MB)
```

I cannot ping the server. I cannot ssh my IP address and loopback (says `port 22: Connection refused`).

EDIT:
Here is my ssh configuration file:

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Comment: Are you certain that the other device is actually up and responding to that IP?

Comment: @vidarlo Yes. It actually works with some other PC. I can connect the PC to the router. It seems the laptop has some problem.

Comment: Yes, something is wrong. You have 0 RX packets on enp3s0f1.

Comment: show us your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. are you dejecting packets from / to port 22 with your firewall? is the server doing that.? either the traffic is being blocked, or the server is running on a different port.

Comment: @j0h The post is updated with the configuration file. I am not sure if the firewall does that. Server listens on port 22.

Comment: do you have access to the machine you are trying to ssh into? can you check if the ssh service is running? $`ps aux | grep ssh` should tell you.

Comment: @j0h That is a router and yes it is running since I can connect to it by ssh using another computer (desktop). Although, my laptop does not have the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and instead has `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. The desktop that is able to connect to the router has `sshd_config` file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that your networking is not set up correctly after switching to non Auto DHCP mode.

Your route table shows:

```
default         rtr-35-12-211-1 0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s0
```

which means that your **default** route is set through the WiFi interface.
That will make you ethernet packets be routed to the 35.12.211.0/24 network making your destination SSH server unreachable.